# Py4JJavaError: An error ocurred while caling z:comjohnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.PythonResourceDownloader.getDownloadSize: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, pre-trained-model, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

Unable to load pre-trained model on both window and linux. set environment variables for all spark 3.2.1 ,hadoop 3.2, sparknlp 3.4.4 and 4.0.0 used both, python 3.8+ and using java 8. Need help

```
from sparknlp.base import *
from sparknlp.annotator import *
from sparknlp.pretrained import PretrainedPipeline
import sparknlp

spark = sparknlp.start()
pipeline = PretrainedPipeline('cardiffnlp/twitter-xlm-roberta-base-sentiment', lang='en')
```

ERROR IS:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 
z:com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.PythonResourceDownloader.getDownloadSize.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/AmazonClientException
at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.S3ResourceDownloader.awsGateway$lzycompute(S3ResourceDownloader.scala:47)
at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.S3ResourceDownloader.awsGateway(S3ResourceDownloader.scala:47)
at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.S3ResourceDownloader.downloadMetadataIfNeed(S3ResourceDownloader.scala:65)
at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.S3ResourceDownloader.resolveLink(S3ResourceDownloader.scala:70)
at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.S3ResourceDownloader.getDownloadSize(S3ResourceDownloader.scala:204)
at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.ResourceDownloader$.getDownloadSize(ResourceDownloader.scala:544)
at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.PythonResourceDownloader$.getDownloadSize(ResourceDownloader.scala:714)
at com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.pretrained.PythonResourceDownloader.getDownloadSize(ResourceDownloader.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 20 more
```